# Java randomUUID broken on android?

Tags: java, android, uuid

We are using java's `UUID.randoumUUID` function to generate UUID across different android devices.
We are facing regular collisions. Are we overlooking something or is it a buggy implementation in android's java.
Is there any known workaround?

***Edit***
providing the code used

```
import java.util.UUID;

public String GenerateGUID() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

Comment: Provide the code showing the UUID usage. You may be using it wrong. The  collision probability is incredibly low, regular collisions are unlikely.

Comment: I have added the code snippet below the question

Comment: I believe I have encountered a member whose UUID.randomUUID() method continues to return dupes. I have instrumented my code on his device, and I am seeing multiple duplicated results returned from this method; the same string is returned within minutes of the prior allegedly random GUID. Would love to know the cause...

Answer (score 0):

Your IMEI no can be your UUID which is never broken and you can use it at your convenience

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String uuid = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: what is the purpose ? may be i can provide you alternate solution.